# HP Active Stylus disconnecting continuously on HP Pavilion X360 2-in-1 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers

I recently bought the HP Pavilion X360 2-in-1 (15-cr0xxx) laptop for the purpose of upgrading another tablet laptop combo, but the stylus that came with it (HP Active Stylus; SPEN-HP-01) has problems that does not appear on the original laptop (Acer Spin 1). The problem is that the pen, when writing, occasionally disconnects and reconnects creating a gap within the line. The link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/31AWv.jpg ) helps visualize the problem. Despite not picking up the pen, continuous breaks appear.

I thought this issue would be resolved with reinstalling the Pen driver, but after repeated deletes and refreshes within Device Manager, the problem still persists. The pen is not the source of the problem because I cannot replicate the problem on the other laptop. This leads me to believe that the problem is the HP laptop's drivers, but I am at a loss at how to continue. All my searches lead me to separate problems and don't address mine.

I also do not know where to find the drivers in the support page for this specific model laptop. In command prompt (systeminfo), the model says: "HP Pavilion x360 Convertible 15-cr0xxx" but that does not help. In the sales page, the model is: "15-cr0037wm" but even with that, it yields no results.

I'm just looking for potential leads because I've tried my hand and I'm at a loss, and am in need for some help before I factory reset this computer (if that would even help).

Upon further inspection, holding the stylus at an angle provides a continuous line (but wiggly), while holding it perpendicular to the screen creates the line breaks. ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxfAR.jpg ) I don't know if that helps, but there's that...

OS: Windows 10 (x64)

Comment: I decided to reinstall Windows and the problem still occured, even showing symptoms in the installation screen, (holding pen onto screen shows clicking animation every few seconds, indicating a loss of connection) leading me to believe it was just a hardware error in the laptop.

Comment: For anyone else with this oddly specific problem, I fixed it by cutting the tip of the stylus's point so it'd be closer to the screen, allowing a better connection between the pen and the computer